# removing directories and all sub-directories in it

Tags: c++, windows, file-io

I wrote a function which should delete a directory and all files and folders in it, but it got some troubles.
For my targets, I made special directory for experiments. This directory stores some files and one folder. And this folder (sub-directory) also contains 1 or 2 files. My function successfuly removes sub-directory and all files in it. And all files in main directory are also removes successfuly. But when the function starts to remove main directory - it fails. It seems like rmdir returns not 0 and I dont know why, cause sub directory removes well.

**As an argument it takes string like "D:\new\".**

Where new is main directory that should be removed whith everything in it. 
*Here is code of this function:*

```
 void OperationsWithDirectories::RemovingCycle(string _path)
    {
        string wayToFile;           // string to hold the path to the directory without mask 
        string deletedFile;         // string which would hold the way to deleting file
        wayToFile = _path;

        _path += "*.*";             // add a mask to the _path string


        _finddata_t* fileinfo = new _finddata_t;

        long done = _findfirst(_path.c_str(), fileinfo);

        int IsContinue = done;

while (IsContinue != -1)
{
    deletedFile = wayToFile + fileinfo->name;

    if (fileinfo->attrib == _A_SUBDIR)
    {
        if (strcmp(fileinfo->name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(fileinfo->name, "..") != 0)
        {
            cout << "\nEnter subdirectory\n";
            RemovingCycle(wayToFile + fileinfo->name + "\\");       //recursive func wich would start, if subdirectory is exist
            cout << "\nOutta subdirectory\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ((remove(deletedFile.c_str())) != 0)
            cout << "\n\n ERROR IN FILE DELETING\n\n";
        else
            cout << endl << deletedFile << " - was deleted";
    }

    IsContinue = _findnext(done, fileinfo);
}

if ((_rmdir(wayToFile.c_str())) != 0)
    cout << "\n\nERROR IN DIRECT - " << wayToFile << " DELETING\n\n";
else
    cout << "\ndir - " << wayToFile << " was deleted succesfully\n";
```

}

Comment: If this is Windows, why not use the requisite Windows API functions to remove a directory?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  Also, I suggest you run this under a debugger, single stepping at a time, and especially for something like this.  Why?  What if something goes wrong, i.e. a variable is set incorrectly, and because of that, you start deleting directories that you didn't mean to delete?

Comment: Yes, sure, I run this code under debugger. It definitely could be painful to delete wrong directories. And about API...I even don't now is it right to use such things in studying, cause I'm beginner and I'm trying to learn basic things of cpp.

Comment: If your compiler is up-to-date enough to support the standard *filesystem* Technical Specification this could be quite simple: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/remove

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this under Windows? In Windows in particular the problem is that if you remove a file or subfolder, it is not removed immediately but asynchronously "sometime in the future". This can take even quite a long time, especially if someone still has some of the file handles open. And even if not, if your program is "too fast" (or the filesystem under heavy load), when you try to remove the parent folder, the contents might not have been actually removed yet, and the call fails.

Commonly this is solved by moving each sub-file and sub-folder to some temporary location (on the same partition!), and then deleting it. That way the parent folder will be empty and deletable, even though the contents has not been "physically" deleted yet (because everything is already moved outside - the move is synchronous).

You can see this talk for more info on that: https://youtu.be/uhRWMGBjlO8?t=7m30s

In general, handling the filesystem properly really isn't all that simple and there is a lot of space for race conditions.

You can confirm this problem if you put a sleep before deleting each folder, lets say 200ms, to see if giving the system some time to delete the contents "solves" the issue (however that is not a "real solution", it is just to see that it is indeed a timing issue).

Note that it is not a problem if you move-and-delete and your program terminates before the actual deletion happens - once the delete returned successfully, the Windows OS will take care that the file will be deleted.

Comment: Yes, it is under Windows. Thanks for answer! I'll try to do it that way now.

Comment: Alternatively instead of moving the contents to a temp location, you can wait until it gets deleted by checking if it exists and then proceed further.

Comment: The problem with waiting is that it is difficult to say when it is actually deleted, so that might need unnecessary waiting (and still sometimes it might not help to wait even for a minute or more, if some program is holding the handle).

Comment: Thank you axalis! Method with directory moving works well!